# sendKeys is not entering the complete input all the time

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have written my script in Java and it is running in Chrome browser. I have a username field, password field and a login button. Even before completing the entry in username field, it is started performing action on password field/login button.

Here is my code,

```
driver.findElement(By.name("data[Student][email]")).sendKeys("abc@mail.com");                   
driver.findElement(By.name("data[Student][password]")).sendKeys("abc123");                
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='btn btn-large btn-primary']")).click();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ! A little remark on your question : you may format the code using markdown (via a button or ctrl-k). Regarding your actual provlem, I'm not sure I understand you well. Does it submit the form before finishing filling login and password ?

Comment: Can you please add the HTML code snippet relating to the elements: email, password? It will be then easier to comprehend, what went wrong with the code above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try slowing down the execution by adding some *sleep* in between, something like

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.name("data[Student][email]")).sendKeys("abc@mail.com");      
Thread.sleep(1000);             
driver.findElement(By.name("data[Student][password]")).sendKeys("abc123");                
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='btn btn-large btn-primary']")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use implicit wait as per below :

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```