# sendKeys() not inserting the full value using WebDriverWait through Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

sendKeys() is not inserting the full string to the text field. I was trying to insert an email id.

```
String name = "New Apollo33";
fluent_wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("businessname"))).sendKeys(name);

String email = "apollo33@mailinator.com";
fluent_wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("businessemail"))).sendKeys(email);
```

It's inserting the name but not fully inserting the email id.

Comment: You should consider breaking it down into at least two steps, maybe more.  Use a fluent wait, create a WebElement, clear the text, send the text.  You're not clearing any pre-existing text.  That's not the problem, but combining the other three steps into one is not always the best idea.

Comment: Also, presence just means that the element is in the DOM, not that it is visible, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sendKeys is not entering the complete input all the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26990436/sendkeys-is-not-entering-the-complete-input-all-the-time)

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue while automating one of my test cases while entering a pre-formatted phone number field. Here is what I did to make sure the script is able to enter the text in the text box:

- Check manually that the text box accepts the text length that the script is trying to enter. It never hurts to check twice :).
- Enter the value using sendKeys and get the value of the element from the DOM.
- While the value of the text box element in DOM is not equal to the text you are trying to enter, then try again.
- Make sure you put an exit condition to your while loop, so that you have a way to exit your test.

Your implementation can be something like this:

```
Wait<WebDriver> fluent_wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                           .withTimeout(60, SECONDS)
                           .pollingEvery(2, SECONDS) 
                           .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

WebElement emailElement= fluent_wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {

     public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
     return driver.findElement(By.id("businessemail"));
}
});
String emailText = "apollo33@mailinator.com";
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); // This is to run the while loop for a specified amount of time and use it as an exit condition for the while loop.

//the below condition assumes that the text box sets some kind of attribute in the DOM element once the user enters the value in the text box.
while(!emailElement.getAttribute("value").equals(emailText)&&System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) < 2000){
     emailElement.clear();
     emailElement.sendKeys(emailText);
}
//if the above doesn't work, add the below as a fall back:
if(!emailElement.getAttribute("value").equals(emailText)){
    emailElement.clear();
    for(char ch: emailText.toCharArray()){
        emailElement.sendKeys(String.valueOf(ch));
        try{
           Thread.sleep(15); //making the thread sleep for 15 milliseconds, taking a performance hit to make the sendKeys work.
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
        }
    }
}
```

The fall back condition with the the Thread.sleep will only be executed if the while loop was not able to set the text in the text box on 2 seconds. You can increase the time if 2 seconds/2000ms is not sufficient. The thread.sleep is miniscule 15 ms hit between each character iteration. We incorporated this in our framework to cover a variety of text boxes developed in different front end technologies. This works fine for us as an organization, so hopefully it would work for you as well.

The key above is to not get stuck with pre-defined utilities that selenium provides, instead you would want to play with DOM values and options that Java provides. Hope you are able to find a solution soon to your issue.
Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

As a *thumb rule* while attempting to send a *Character Sequence* instead of invoking `presenceOfElementLocated()` always invoke **`elementToBeClickable()`** and you can use the following solution:

```
fluent_wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("businessname"))).sendKeys("New Apollo33");
fluent_wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("businessemail"))).sendKeys("apollo33@mailinator.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The sendKeys-Keys.chord is not inserting the full value (goes way too fast that the browser has no time to even write it  "sometimes")

**Before:** (doesn't work 100%)

```
action.sendKeys(Keys.chord("string")).perform();
```

That goes way too fast while writting the "string" .. and sometimes (like from 1/5 to 1/10 times) it appears incomplete on the website I'm sending it to. And it's very frustrating..

The solution I tried to apply worked some days for me but eventually the same happened (1/20 but it fails) the solution I tried was simply adding a
"Thread sleep" of 1.5seg after the sendKeys-Keys.chord (maybe the website needed more time to write it):

**After:** (doesn't work 100% - I  tried this possible solution too and it just fails less but still fails 1/20)

```
action.sendKeys(Keys.chord("string")).perform();
Thread.sleep(1500);
```

---

**Final Solution:** (that worked 100%)

Add a do-while that will be comprovating / checking if the sendKeys-Keys.chord matches what actually has been writed on the browser (WebDriver), if it doesn't match it will write it again (you can now reduce the delay from Thread.sleep)

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,40);
Actions action = new Actions(driver);

  String TextSentenceORWordToIntroduce = "Dinosaur";
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("xpath_to_element"))).click();
  Thread.sleep(200);
  action.sendKeys(Keys.chord(TextSentenceORWordToIntroduce)).perform();
  Thread.sleep(500);
  String comprovation = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath_to_element")).getAttribute("value"); // or rarely ")).getText();"

if (!comprovation.contentEquals(TextSentenceORWordToIntroduce)) { // if not then ALL WORKS FINE ;) and won't enter the Do-while
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath_to_element")).click();
    do {
        Thread.sleep(200);
        action.sendKeys(Keys.HOME).perform();
        Thread.sleep(200);
        action.keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).perform();
        Thread.sleep(200);
        action.sendKeys(Keys.END).perform();
        Thread.sleep(200);
        action.keyUp(Keys.SHIFT).perform();
        Thread.sleep(200);
        action.sendKeys(Keys.chord(TextSentenceORWordToIntroduce)).perform();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        comprovation = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath_to_element")).getAttribute("value"); // or rarely ")).getText();"
    } while (!comprovation.contentEquals(TextSentenceORWordToIntroduce));
}
```

---

Hope this solution can help someone with the same problem ^^

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem wherein sending the keys as a single String would enter a single character only using the below:

```
public void enterText(WebElement element, String text){
    element.clear();
    element.sendKeys(text);
}
```

My solution was to convert the String into an array of characters and enter each character individually as below:

```
public void enterTextCharByChar(WebElement element, String charSeq){
    char[] inputText = charSeq.toCharArray();
    // clear any pre-existing text
    element.clear();
    for (char val : inputText) {
        element.sendKeys(String.valueOf(val));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I frequently find sendKeys() moves too fast or inputs incomplete strings.
You'll need to wrap this in a while loop with a very small delay:

```
while(element.text != input) {
    element.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"), input); //or whatever
    Thread.sleep(100) //100ms not 100sec
}
```

I know thread.sleep is heavily frowned upon, however a waitFor() would take just as long

```
element.clear()
```

also works, but use either clear() or Ctrl+a + input as using both is redundant

Comment: As the OP noted, part of the text is making it, not all, and he's not clearing the text beforehand (neither are you).  This would potentially keep contatonating text and get in an infinite loop.

Comment: This can still easily get into an infinite loop. You have no exit from the `while`. It would be better to send one character at a time with a brief pause between characters and then at the end assert if the string is complete or not.

Comment: im for quick readability, not iterating over a string one char at a time. hamfisted or not, this approach gets the user moving again. if we're stuck in a loop, we're not waiting long enough. if OP wants an infallible method they should override sendkeys themselves.